# JavaFX - Get CheckBox properties from outside GUIController

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, javafx

In JavaFX I want to check if a checkbox is selected and I want to do this using the `lookup(#id)` method. However this method returns a `Node`, which doesn't have the `isSelected()` method.

The code below shows the `GUIController` and a class `Visualize` it calls, where the status of the checkbox is read. I added a solution (reading the checkbox properties in GUIController and passing them to Visualize), but this is not how I want to proceed. I whish that the checkbox status is read in Visualize, because there will be many other GUI elements that I need to read so it is more compact to pass on a single object to Visualize instead of a list precomputed in GUIController.

Thank you for suggestions!

GUI Controller:

```
public class GUIController implements Initializable {

@FXML private AnchorPane RootPane;
@FXML private CheckBox TextCheckBox;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    Boolean TextCheckBoxSelected = TextCheckBox.isSelected();

    Visualize visualizeInstance = new Visualize();
    root3D = visualizeInstance.draw(RootPane, TextCheckBoxSelected);

    /* ... */
```

Class called by GUIController:

```
public class Visualize {

public Visualize() {
    //
}

public Group draw(AnchorPane RootPane, Boolean TextCheckBoxSelected) {

    System.out.println(RootPane.lookup("#TextCheckBox"));
    System.out.println(TextCheckBoxSelected);

    /* ... */
```

Output:

```
CheckBox[id=TextCheckBox, styleClass=check-box]'Text'
true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it this way, just downcast the result of the `lookup`:

```
public class Visualize {


    // ...

    public Group draw(AnchorPane rootPane) {
        CheckBox textCheckBox = (CheckBox) rootPane.lookup("#TextCheckBox");
        boolean selected = textCheckBox.isSelected();
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you are doing this because you need your `Visualize` object to respond to changes in the `CheckBox`'s selected state, then consider passing a `BooleanProperty` instead, which you can observe if you need:

```
public class Visualize {

    private BooleanProperty selectedProperty ;

    public Visualize(BooleanProperty selectedProperty) {
        this.selectedProperty = selectedProperty ;
        // ...
    }
    // ...

    public Group draw() {
        boolean selected = selectedProperty.get();
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
Visualize visualizeInstance = new Visualize(textCheckBox.selectedProperty());
root3D = visualizeInstance.draw();
```